# Conceito - Menu web dinâmico

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aplicação-web

Estou idealizando um projeto pessoal e estou com dúvida a respeito de melhores práticas.

Para um sistema WEB com controle de acesso, qual das opções a seguir, na opinião de vocês, é a mais ideal?

1 - Montar um menu estático, com todas as opções já criadas, ler as informações de acesso do usuário do banco, enviar para o formulário no primeiro acesso e ocultar os menus que o mesmo não possuir acesso?

2 - Deixar um *holder* isolado para o menu, ler no banco de dados os menus que o usuário tem acesso e então montar a estrutura de acesso e retornar no *holder*?

É claro que essas são as ideias que eu tive, possivelmente não são as melhores e nem as mais corretas. Nesse caso, alguém saberia me indicar uma boa alternativa ? Alguma fonte de recursos/exemplos também será bem vinda.

Obrigado!

Comment: Acho que um simples `ng-if="usuario.acesso == 1"` já resolveria. Outra opção interessante seria o uso de tokens.